# MVC Llamar modelo de otra entidad

Tags: php, mvc

Estoy trabajando con CodeIgniter y como sabrán PHP es bastante libre y nos deja hacer muchas cosas, a veces malas practicas.

La pregunta es mas teorica que del Framework. En una arquitectura MVC, es mala practica llamar al modelo de otra entidad?
Ej:

```
    Controller:
    - Garantia
    - Novedad
   Modelo
    - Model_Garantia
    - Model_Novedad
```

Es decir, llamar desde el Controller Garantía al modelo Novedad cumpliría con los principios SOLID, de POO y MVC? O debería crear un objeto tipo Novedad y a través de ese buscar lo que necesito del Model_Novedad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no es mala practica realizar consulta de otro modelos, en un proyecto usted tiene que realizar varias consulta para traer datos foráneos un ejemplo seria: la de los pedidos y venta donde tiene que traer datos como los articulos y clientes. lo que si tiene que esta bien estandarizado,en una tabla mysql en un solo controlador con el mismo nombre para evitar confusiones 
llamar varios modelos

```
$this->load->model(array(
            'MunicipiosModel',
            'DepartamentosModel'
        ));
```

Comment: Perfecto! Es como esta hecho! Pero pensando en POO, pensé que sería mejor que se haga una nueva instancia de Novedad y a través de ella traer las Novedades de una Garantía. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Al implementar una servicio web RESTful con una arquitectura MVC con algo básico como un CRUD es necesario saber que la especificación indica que debe de llamarse en cada uno de los controladores la entidad/modelo para la que fue diseñada.

Partiendo de Los Principios de SOLID el primero es *Principio de responsabilidad única* que establece:

> Cada módulo o clase debe tener responsabilidad sobre una sola parte de la funcionalidad proporcionada por el software y esta responsabilidad debe estar encapsulada en su totalidad por la clase.

Podemos darnos cuenta que al hacer dependiente las clases estarías generando una baja cohesión y un alto acoplamiento. Por lo que al realizar una modificación a una afectaría directamente a la otra clase.

El principal problema que tiene este enfoque RESTful es que si tienes dos Modelos uno llamado *Post* y otro *Comment* lo que indica la especificación para poder llamar a un Post con todos los Comment's asociados sería de la siguiente manera:

```
GET /post/1
{
  "title": "My Post",
  "author": { 
    "firstName": "Angel",
    "lastName": "Oropeza"
  },
  "comments": [1, 2, 3, 4]
  // ... more fields here
}

GET /comment/1
{
  // ... more fields here
}
...
GET /comment/4
{
  // ... more fields here
}
```

Es decir, se debe de hacer una llamada para obtener el Post con id 1 y enseguida realizar una llamada a cada unos de los comentarios asociados a este Post.

Por último mencionar que algunas páginas han migrado sus servicios REST a *GraphQL* como GitHub. Puedes obtener más información al respecto [Aquí](https://graphql.org/).

Comment: En realidad no es un RESTFul ni un CRUD simple, es una aplicacion grande, es más HMVC. Por lo que la necesidad es de generar un reporte de Garantías (las cuales poseen Novedades). La pregunta era si puedo ir al modelo de novedades **saltando** al Controlador de novedades, para buscar las Novedades de la Garantía. Gracias!!

Comment: Excelente el comentario sobre el funcionamiento de una API RESTful, aunque no haya sido la pregunta especifica, me sirvió mucho!